# Drupal cms stacked google bar chart

Tags: php, drupal, charts, drupal-7, google-visualization

I'm having issues generating a stacked bar chart using drupal cms.

I'm making use of this api to generate chart

(https://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools)

as shown:

```
 > $settings['chart']['chartOne'] = array( 
>
     'header' => array('Teachers', 'Student'),
    'rows' => array(array(20, 100)),
        'columns' => array('people'),
        'chartType' => 'BarChart',
        'containerId' => 'content1',
        'options' => array(
            'forceIFrame' => FALSE,
            'title' => 'School',
            'width' => 800,
            'height' => 400,
            'isstacked' => TRUE
        )
```

how can i make it on the chart such that?

example :

10 out of 20 teachers are male and the other 10 are female

50 out of 100 students are male and the other 50 are female

Tried modifying the following and  getting only teachers but empty students:

```
> $settings['chart']['chartOne'] = array( 
    >
           'header' => array('Teachers', 'Students'),
          'rows' => array(array(10),array(10)), array(array(50),array(50)),
        'columns' => array('Male', 'Female'),
            'chartType' => 'BarChart',
            'containerId' => 'content1',
            'options' => array(
                'forceIFrame' => FALSE,
                'title' => 'School',
                'width' => 800,
                'height' => 400,
                'isstacked' => TRUE
            )
```

Output Results : https://i.stack.imgur.com/V86qQ.png

Comment: What did you try so far to achieve it?

Comment: i tried modifying :
    'header' => array('Teachers', 'Student'),
    'rows' => array(array(20=>array(10,10), 100=>array(50,50))),
    'columns' => array('Male','Female'),

but i'm not getting any results

Comment: What do you get with it?

Comment: i'm getting empty results, no charts displayed, even the legend is not appearing and no error messages too

Comment: Did you check how to integrate Google charts with Drupal? Are you doing it Drupal way?

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from the OP which was originally posted into the question*

---

> $settings['chart']['chartOne'] = array(
>
> ```
>            'header' => array('Teachers', 'Students'),
>           'rows' => array(array(10,50),array(10,50)),
>         'columns' => array('Male', 'Female'),
>             'chartType' => 'BarChart',
>             'containerId' => 'content1',
>             'options' => array(
>                 'forceIFrame' => FALSE,
>                 'title' => 'School',
>                 'width' => 800,
>                 'height' => 400,
>                 'isstacked' => TRUE
>             )
> ```